# Jquery input number in multiples (keyup)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make an `input` element accept numbers only in multiples of 50?

I know we can specify `step="50"` as an attribute, but I would prefer a solution that is triggered by [the `keyup` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup).

I found this code, which prevents users from entering a number less than 50.

**Question :** How can I adjust this code so that only multiples of 50 can be entered ?

```js
$('#numberbox').keyup(function(){
  if ($(this).val() < 50){
    alert("Minimum Quantity: 50");
    $(this).val('50');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="numberbox" type='number'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the modulo operator

```
var multiple = 50;

$('#numberbox').keyup(function(){
   if (parseInt($(this).val()) % multiple ) {
      alert("Only multiples of " + multiple + " allowed");
      $(this).val(multiple);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks , This is what i  am looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())** to do this, check the example bellow.

> The remainder operator returns the remainder left over when one operand is divided by a second operand. It always takes the sign of the dividend, not the divisor.

```js
$('#numberbox').keyup(function(){
  if ($(this).val()%50==0){
    $('#result').text($(this).val()+' is multiple of 50');
  }else{
     $('#result').text($(this).val()+' is not a multiple of 50');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="numberbox" type='number'>
<span id='result'></span>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer `blur` instead of `keyup` as `keyup` would keep on alerting. To know if it is multiple of `50` check a condition with `modulo` i.e.`%` like if `parseInt($(this).val())%50 != 0`

```js
$('#numberbox').blur(function(){
  if (parseInt($(this).val())%50 != 0){
    alert("Multiples of 50 should be entered");
    $(this).val('50');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="numberbox" type='number'>
```

Comment: @wordpressuser. No probs.. Happy coding.. :)